# Attach historical data to a non-historical table

Tags: mysql, sql, historical-db

I have two tables with a similar structure in MySQL, one is the updated data and other is the history records for that data, and I need to perform analytics over all data we have there. I thought using a view that aggregates all data in one table would be useful but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a view using `UNION`?

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT field1 AS f1, field2 AS f2 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1 AS f1, field2 AS f2 FROM table2
```

Then perform your analysis over that view.

More docs: [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), [CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).